# Azure Service Bus: How to achieve eventual consistency when a subscriber goes down

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, event-sourcing, eventual-consistency

Currently I am using Azure Service Bus as a means to communicate and keep data consistent among the different services in my platform. However, let's say that one of my services (subscribers) goes down for an extended period of time and is unable to receive any events. Suddenly this service is in an inconsistent state.

Does Azure Service Bus have any type of "event sourcing" solution in place in order to replay my events? I understand that Azure Event Hubs has this feature where I can store events in an append only fashion to azure blob storage. However, the only thing I am finding for Azure Service Bus is the dead letter queue and my understanding that this is only used when no subscribers are capable of processing an event.

Is this something that I will have to build myself?

Comment: Subscribers should only commit a message if it was successfully processed. This way if a subscriber dies the messages will be there when it comes back. Service bus has better reliability guarantees than event hubs so is better suited to transactional messages.

Comment: Okay forgive my ignorance, I am looking at this from a very high level. Let's say I have two subscribers, SubcriberA is able to successfully receive the event, SubscriberB is offline and is not. Does the event stay in the queue until SubscriberB comes back online?

Comment: Yes unlike event hubs, on service bus each subscription gets its own copy of each message meeting the subscription criteria. Imo SB wouldnt make a good event store from an event sourcing point of view. Event hubs is better for ES but note that there's a finite storage time. Persistence to eg storage queues might still be necessary for long term replay.

Answer (score 1):

All events stored in a subscription will be delivered once the consumer is up and running unless the subscription has `DefaultMessageTimeToLive` (TTL) set to purge messages.

Comment: I can't find anything in Azure Service Bus documentation to support this claim? The only thing I am seeing is referring to the dead letter queue, which states: "The purpose the dead-letter queue is to hold messages that cannot be delivered to any receiver, or messages that could not be processed"

Comment: "To support this claim"? I've lost you. A subscription is, in essence, a queue. Are you looking for documentation to spell out that a queue will retain your messages? That's the whole idea behind queueing and messaging  Anyhow, validation is simple. Create a topic with a subscription, publish a message and see if the subscription w/o any consumers retains the message or not. Cheers.

Comment: Additional information - Foundational Capabilities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#foundational-capabilities Service Bus Queues support Atomic operation support.